# Add watermark to different pages

Tags: c#, vb.net, fastreport

I am trying to add a watermark to different pages according to a parameter that comes from the database.

The option I have chosen is the following

```
private void GroupHeader1_BeforePrint (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page1.Watermark.Enabled = ((String) Report.GetColumnValue ("conAlbPro010.CONFORME")) == "N"; 
}
```

But I guess this will paint it on page 1, and I want it to paint on the current page if the value CONFORMED = "N".

Currently it is only painted on page 1

Comment: What is the `Type` of `Page1`? You probably need to access the page collection or whatever it is a child of which might have a `GetCurrent()` (or similar) method.

Comment: `Type` is `ReportPage`, I'm looking for a property that the current page tells me, but I don't see any related property or method

Comment: I have tried to add the modification of the enabled watermark in different events, for example after the header print event, together with a messagebox.show and the event is being fired 6 times in a 3 page page. I do not understand why